# Use regex with sed to replace spaces by underscore

Tags: regex, bash, sed, pcre

I need to replace all the matches of the following PCRE by underscores in a file with sed.

```
/(?:^Node-path: |\G)\S+\K\h+/gm
```

I have tried escaping parenthesis, remove espacing of G, S, K... but still can't get it to work.

Anyone can help plase?

Comment: sed doesn't support pcre. explain what do you want to achieve, better with examples, then someone could help you.

Comment: in a svn dump file, i want to replace all the spaces by underscores in lines starting with "Node-path: " to replace all my branches and tags with spaces in them.

Comment: try this line if it works: `sed '/^Node-path:/s/ /_/g'`

Comment: it almost works, the only problem is that is replaces the space just after "path:" and i have to keep this one

Comment: check the answer below with/out  gnu sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sed is gnu sed, you can mix `NUMBER` and `g` modifier in order to skip the first space:

```
sed '/^Node-path:/s/ /_/2g'
```

If your sed is not gnu sed, the `NUMBER+g` may not be supported. However you can do this trick:

```
sed '/^Node-path:/{s/ /_/g;s/_/ /}'
```

or

```
sed '/^Node-path:/{s/ /_/g;s/:_/: /}'
```